# Hard-coded url in Razor

Tags: c#, xml, razor

Looking for a simple RSS reader for razor syntax in C#,I came across this website: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/27409-Consume-an-RSS-feed-in-Razor.

As it says in the comments in the code, it maybe the URL is hardcoded. I curious how exactly is it hardcoded to one RSS feed, it doesn't seem obvious looking at the code. For example, if I tried to replace the url for "http://tdsb.on.ca/RSS/MediaRoom.xml", it simply goes blank.

```
@using System.Xml;

@{
//Get the XML from remote URL
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

**//URL currently hardcoded - but you could use a macro param to pass in URL**
xml.Load("http://blog.orcare.com/rss");

//Select the nodes we want to loop through
XmlNodeList nodes = xml.SelectNodes("//item");

//Traverse the entire XML nodes.
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    //Get the value from the <title> node
    var title = node.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;

    //Get the value from the <description> node
    var description = node.SelectSingleNode("description").InnerText;

    <h1>@title</h1>
    @Html.Raw(description)

 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what the author means is that the URL itself is hardcoded; i.e. not dynamically loaded from a database, configuration files, a user interface or similar, but written in the code itself. In a real solution you would often like this to be more dynamic if you do not only want RSS from a static feed or a static list of feeds. But if you never need to change the url once you're in production with the code, then it is not a problem that it is hard coded.

Without having tried the code out myself, from a first impression it should work with any url that returns an actual RSS feed. As long as the feed has item nodes in the XML, and as long as the item nodes have a title and a description.

But the code is not very solid. It can easily break if either of these elements are missing from the XML.

Answer (score 0):

It's hardcoding where it goes to fetch the rss feed.  `http://tdsb.on.ca/RSS/MediaRoom.xml`goes blank because the format doesn't match. If you open up both xmls and compare, you will find `tdsb` is missing `description` under `ìtem`.

Comment: But I find that even after getting rid of tags which refer to description and instead just trying to get the link, it still gives me a blank page. Is there at least some way I can view the compiler results?